# Problem: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager throwing exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am having this strange case, at first time when the page loades, everything goes fine. But as soon as I click on any link which makes any ajax request, after that, I get this error while trying to read the configuration.

"System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException"

I am using asp.net mvc 1.0[image: please refer the attached screenshot]
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the source where it breaks please?

Comment: And the full exception stacktrace including the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming because of an ajax request which was having one of the route data parameter with space eg. www.domain.com/account/index/%20routedata. In this case, the firebug was showing 404 not found error while as debugging was enabled on the machine, it was throwing the above mentioned exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WebConfigurationManager and not ConfigurationManager in a web project.

Comment: Personally I believe that there is no such issue in using configurationmanager in web projects. Or is there? The problem was coming because of an ajax request which was having one of the route data parameter with space eg. www.domain.com/account/index/%20routedata. In this case, the firebug was showing 404 not found error while as debugging was enabled on the machine, it was throwing the above mentioned exception. Thanks for your precious time. :)